# how to add html content to document

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to convert html to pdf.I have a html code.
Ex:

```
var example_html = @"<p>This
                        <em>is</em>
                        <span class=""
                              headline""
                              style=""text-decoration: underline;"">some</span>
                        <strong>sample
                            <em>text</em>
                        </strong>
                        <span style=""color: red;"">!!!</span>
                    </p>";
```

I have added the below code to generate this html content to pdf but its throwing an error saying "the documnet has no pages"

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
using (Document doc = new Document())
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);
    doc.Open();
    //doc.Add(new Paragraph(example_html));
    using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath("~/GST/HTMLtoPDF.aspx")))
    {
        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, reader);
    }
    doc.Close();
}
Response.End();
```

In doc i need to pass or add my html content right?? But i dont know how to add my html content so that it can parse it into pdf.Kindly help.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error stated you aren't adding pages to the document. The following code worked for me the it returns a PDF title MyDoc.pdf.

In your question you mention you wanted to convert the *example_html* into PDF but the code sample is reading a file named *HTMLtoPDF.aspx*. Make sure the file has that HTML. I tried reading from the file and from the variable directly and it works in both situations.

To add more pages you call **NewPage** method and HTML to that page as shown below:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    HttpContext.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/PDF";
    HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "MyDoc.pdf");

    var page1 = @"<p>PAGE 1 This <em>is </em><span class=""headline"" style=""text-decoration: underline;"">some</span> <strong>sample <em> text</em></strong><span style=""color: red;"">!!!</span></p>";
    var page2 = @"<p>PAGE 2 This <em>is </em><span class=""headline"" style=""text-decoration: underline;"">some</span> <strong>sample <em> text</em></strong><span style=""color: red;"">!!!</span></p>";
    var page3 = @"<p>PAGE 3 This <em>is </em><span class=""headline"" style=""text-decoration: underline;"">some</span> <strong>sample <em> text</em></strong><span style=""color: red;"">!!!</span></p>";

    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (Document doc = new Document())
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);
        doc.Open();

        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, new StringReader(page1));

        // To add more pages you can call NewPage and add other HTML snippets
        doc.NewPage();
        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, new StringReader(page2));
        doc.NewPage();
        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, new StringReader(page3));
    }

    return View();
}
```

This sample creates a 3-page PDF with different HTML on each page

Comment: [Thanks for your reply.In your reply you have not used example_html.I want to generate pdf using example_html and not using my Server.MapPath("HTMLtoPDF.aspx").So can you tell me how exactly to do that] @volkan

Comment: @Rakesh: Just comment out the current ParseXHtml line and uncomment  the one using the StringReader

Comment: You need to find out from the application pool for the website what is the identity it is running under (by default this is Application Pool Identity) and grant that the correct permissions.

Comment: [Throwing "Invalid nested tag td found, expected closing tag center." even though there are equal number of tds.And also my html is different from the example given above.Your code is working fine for my given example but not for my html code.]@volkan

Comment: @Rakesh: You're clearly trying with a different HTML that includes td tags, not the sample above. The above code works with the sample HTML. Check your HTML and add missing closing tags.

Comment: [I am running my application locally.I am not trying to publish my site using IIS]@sbouaked

Comment: [Thanks a lot @volkan.Its generating pdf but the problem is its generating pdf for only one page.My html has 3 pages.Any solution?]@volkan

Comment: @Rakesh: I've updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @Rakesh: Cool, I'm glad it worked out.. I'd appreciate if you accepted the answer then.

Comment: [I have voted for your answer but its saying i need have my reputation above 5 so..]@volkan

Comment: @Rakesh: You may not upvote now but you can accept the answer as you asked the question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . No problem anyway, just wanted to mention it for future reference

Comment: [Got it.Accepted your answer]@VolkanPaksoy

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 //HTMLString = Pass your Html , fileLocation = File Store Location
        public void converttopdf(string HTMLString, string fileLocation)
        {
            Document document = new Document();

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();

            List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(HTMLString), null);
            for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
            {
                document.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
            }

            document.Close();
        }
```

with http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/itextsharp/iTextSharp-5.4.1/

Comment: Can you explain what you did, and why that fixes the problem?

Comment: [Thanks for your reply.Its throwing an error saying "Access is denied to my file location".I have tried running VS as administrator but still not working]@sbouaked